# How to find sum of all descendents attribute named x in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

As i have tree structure in my graph database ArangoDB like below

The node with id 2699394 is a parent node of this graph tree. and each node has attribute named X assigned to it. I want to know sum of x of all the descendants of parent node 2699394 exclusive of its own attribute x in sum.
for example suppose if,

```
 2699399 x value is = 5,
 2699408 x value is = 3,
 2699428 x value is = 2,
 2699418 x value is = 5,

then parent node 2699394 sum of x should be = 5 + 3 + 2 + 5 
                                            = 15
```

so the answer is 15. So can anybody give me query for this calculation in ArangoDB AQL?

To find out no of descendants of particular node, i have used below query,

```
`FOR v, e, p   in 1..1000 OUTBOUND 'Person/1648954' 
GRAPH 'Appes'
RETURN v.id`
```

Thanks in Advance.
Mayank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that children are linked to their parents, the data could be visualized like this:

```
nodes/2699394 SUM of children?
      ↑
nodes/2699399 {x: 5}
      ↑
nodes/2699408 {x: 3}
      ↑
nodes/2699428 {x: 2}
      ↑
nodes/2699418 {x: 5}
```

To walk the chain of children, we need to traverse in INBOUND direction (or OUTOBUND if parent nodes point to children):

```
FOR v IN 1..10 INBOUND "nodes/2699394" relations
  RETURN v
```

In this example, an anonymous graph is used by specifying an edge collection *relations*. You can also use a named graph, like `GRAPH "yourGraph"`.

Starting at `nodes/2699394`, the edges down to `nodes/2699418` are traversed and every node on the way is returned unchanged so far.

Since we are only interested in the `x` attribute, we can change that to only return that attribute: `RETURN v.x` - which will return `[ 5, 3, 2, 5 ]`. Unless we say `IN 0..10`, the start vertex will not be included.

Inside the FOR loop, we don't have access to all the `x` values, but only one at a time. We can't do something like `RETURN SUM(v.x)` here. Instead, we need to assign the result of the traversal to a variable, which makes it a sub-query. We can then add up all the numbers and return the resulting value:

```
LET x = (
  FOR v IN 1..10 INBOUND "nodes/2699394" relations
    RETURN v.x
)
RETURN SUM(x) // [ 15 ]
```

If you want to return the start node with a computed `x` attribute, you may do the following:

```
LET doc = DOCUMENT("nodes/2699394")
LET x = (
  FOR v IN 1..10 INBOUND doc relations
    RETURN v.x
)
RETURN MERGE( doc, { x: SUM(x) } )
```

The result will be like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "nodes/2699394",
    "_key": "2699394",
    "_rev": "2699394",
    "x": 15
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Codemanx, your answer is almost correct. but i have used named graph as shown in my previous query to find all the descendants of the node. So how to do in that case? You can take reference of my below query  FOR v, e, p   in 1..1000 OUTBOUND 'Person/1648954' 
GRAPH 'Appes'
RETURN v.id`

Comment: As I pointed out, you can also use a named graph. Simply replace `relations` by `GRAPH yourGraph`.

Comment: As to count sum of descendants of each node, i have started bottom to top approach means first of all i find sum of descendants of node nodes/2699418 that is the last node, then nodes/2699428, then nodes/2699408 like... so if i already calculated value of last node descendants then at the time of calculation of his parent node is there any way to get value of already calculated node and just add immediate descendants value. No need to calculate again and again same thing.

Comment: Instead of just returning the computed value, you could `UPDATE doc WITH { x } IN nodes` so that you can access it later. But I would not call it `x` to avoid confusion, maybe `xCached` or something like this is better? You could then explicitly check for that attribute (`HAS(doc, "xCached")`) and use it - but be careful not to use it for different paths that would otherwise result in different sums for `x`.